# Définition of mixing time

Tags: group-theory, probability-theory, random-walk

I’m a noob in random walks theory on groups.

I don’t understand what does mixing time of a random walk is.

They say it is something about convergence to a steady distribution. Like all I understand so far about random walk is that if you are at a given position, there is a distribution on the set of generators that you will multiply next. So like that distribution is fixed.

> So what do they mean by steady distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the random walk on the n-cycle, i.e., set $n \geq 2$ and $w_k = e^{i\frac{2k\pi}{n}}$ for all $k \in \{0, \dots, n\}$. Starting from $0$, you have $\frac{1}{2}$ chance to go in the direct sense, $\frac{1}{2}$ to go in the indirect sense.

It should be pretty clear that, after a very long time, you are in each position with probability $\frac{1}{n}$.

The mixing time is the time after which, starting from any distribution on the $n$-cycle, your distribution will be almost exactly uniform.

Interestingly there is often a cut-off phenomena, i.e. just before the mixing time your distribution is far from uniform, and right after this time your distribution is very close to uniform.

Comment: Thank you sir, may I ask what are some of the applications of random walk on finite groups in the real world?

Comment: Imagine you have a deck of cards. You want it to be perfectly mixed, but you don't want to spend 3 days mixing it either. Then, if you know its mixing time, you can, in some sense, shuffle it just the right amount of time.

Comment: Now there are some statistical methods which are heavely used that rely on that idea. If you want to simulate a law $\mu$ but don't know how to do so, you can take a markov chain whose distribution converge towards $\mu$ and let it run for enough time. But, if you want a good estimation of $\mu$, you will need $10^6$ simulations of this Markov chain or so... hence you probably don't want to spend too much extra time on each one.